# Not getting the search result

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I just start learning Flask and i'm trying to use a simple search form on my news headline site but when i submit the search it seems that it's not working, i'm using a simple flask get request
Here is my code:

```
import feedparser
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
rss_feed = {'wsj': "https://feeds.a.dj.com/rss/RSSWSJD.xml",
            'cnbc': "https://www.cnbc.com/id/100003114/device/rss/rss.html",
            'washington_post': "http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/rss/politics?itid=lk_inline_manual_2"}

@app.route("/")
def get_news():
    query = request.args.get('publication')
    if not query or query.lower not in rss_feed:
        publication = 'wsj'
    else:
        publication = query.lower

    feed = feedparser.parse(rss_feed[publication])
    return render_template("home.html", articles=feed['entries'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

and my html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Headlines</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>Headlines</h1>
            <form>
          <input type="text" name="publication" placeholder="search">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
            {% for article in articles %}
            <b><a href="{{article.link}}">{{article.title}}</a></b><br />
            <i>{{ article.published }}</i><br />
            <p>{{ article.summary }}</p>
    <hr />
    {% endfor %}
        </body>
</html>
```

Now when i submit a search for 'cnbc' it still display the result for 'wsj' what wrong with my code?

Comment: please go through `javascript` and `ajax` - to dynamically change your html after a server API is called.

Comment: Use breakpoints it's the better way for understanding and finding any errors. Provide the requested URL to get a full detail of the issue.

Comment: the requested url depend on the search if i'm searching for 'cnbc' for example the requested url will be http://127.0.0.1:5000/?publication=cnbc

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add 4 different notes in the code as comment, please have a look in the Glossary.
Here is the solution:

> > > Python file, here is where the error occur, long stoyry short your if statement was always returning True, hence the publication variable was set as 'wsj

```
import feedparser
from flask import render_template, request, Flask
# Note 1

app = Flask(__name__)
rss_feed = {'wsj': "https://feeds.a.dj.com/rss/RSSWSJD.xml",
            'cnbc': "https://www.cnbc.com/id/100003114/device/rss/rss.html",
            'washington_post': "http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/rss/politics?itid=lk_inline_manual_2"}


@app.route("/")
def get_news():
    
    
    if request.args.get('publication'):
        query = request.args.get('publication').lower() # Note 2
        print(f'Query is : {query}') # Note 4
        if not query or query not in rss_feed: # Note 3
            print('Publication is wsj') # Note 4
            publication = 'wsj'
        else:
            print('Publication is the query entry') # Note 4
            publication = query

        feed = feedparser.parse(rss_feed[publication])

        return render_template("view.html", articles=feed['entries'])
    return render_template("view.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

> > > HTML File

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Headlines</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Headlines</h1>
        <!-- Note 5 -->
        <form method="GET"> 
          <input type="text" name="publication" placeholder="search">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
            {% for article in articles %}
  
            <b><a href="{{article.link}}">{{article.title}}</a></b><br />
            <i>{{ article.published }}</i><br />
            <p>{{ article.summary }}</p>
            <hr />
            {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

> **NOTES GLOSSARY**

- Note 1: Have the imports from the same package in the same line
- Note 2: Rather then check the query if is lower is better to turn it lower already in the variable as I did.
- Note 3: Here is where the real issue was. This statement was always True hence setting the 'publication' variable as 'wsj'. This is because of add 'query.lower' not in rss_feed which obsiously it wasn't. And by the way you should have done it 'query.lower()'
- Note 4: Just a reminder to How to find and troubleshot your code.The print() function is the first thing to learn in python and is the most usefull tool for this matter. This is how I found the error in less then 5 minutes because I let the code 'Speak' through the terminal.
- Note 5: Few suggestion here, first add a method='GET' (not neccessary) just for readability. Then indent better the HTML file as it was all messed around.

Another solution that may be slightly clearer is this:

```
@app.route("/")
def get_news():
    
    if request.args.get('publication'):
        query = request.args.get('publication').lower() 
        if not query or query not in rss_feed: 
            publication = 'wsj'
            feed = feedparser.parse(rss_feed[publication])
            return render_template("view.html", articles=feed['entries'])
        
        publication = query
        feed = feedparser.parse(rss_feed[publication])
        return render_template("view.html", articles=feed['entries'])
    return render_template("view.html")
```

Comment: thanks a lot @FedericoBaù but why are you returning view.html two times ?

Comment: The first one (return render_template("view.html")) is to render the template and show you the HTML web page. As you can see there isn't the articles=feed['entries'] variable (otherwise would raise an error)  The second one is to show the search result after the If statement

Comment: In this case, because your are using a html form and the result of the form is in the same page, you wanna stay in the same page and just render new Items. But this approach is more obvious if you redirect somewhere else. There is the ```return redirect(url_for('example'))``` that is used like this so. First you render the template and then after the IF statement (normally because of a form) it redirects, but because you don't go nowhere it seems bit odd.